# Creating Conditional Formatting Referencing the Adjacent Cell to the Left

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[Our Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb29e.png)

I'm trying to create a conditional format that will assist my team build a schedule that identifies when they have accidentally scheduled someone on an early shift following a late shift. I'm in over my head...

Our late shifts (LD, LC, LFC) could not be followed by an early shift (ED, EC, EFC). I'm trying to find a formula that identifies that if a cell contains ED, EC, or EFC AND the cell immediately to the left is LD, LC, or LFC THEN format the cell.

I tried playing with the XLOOKUP function but couldn't visualize a way to apply it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have some basic understanding of how to apply conditional formatting, you could try the following solution.

I used the following example to demonstrate the solution. I suggest do NOT start your data in column A. Start your data in column B.

Before applying the conditional formatting, I have given names to two ranges:

List_ES - being a list containing all the codes for early shifts

List_LS - being a list containing all the codes for late shifts

Once the two lists have been defined, highlight the whole area of the data, in my example, it is range B2:G4, open the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager, and use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(AND(MATCH(B2,List_LS,0)>0,MATCH(A2,List_ES,0)),FALSE)
```

[image: Solution]